# How to do expanding functions using Pandas on Time Series

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Ideally I would like it to end up like this (notice the modelIDs grouped together and expanding_mean, expanding_median functions, SaleCount etc. to date):

[image]

I have tried sorting the data and reindexing by 'saledate' then using 'group_by' to perform functions per modelID but cannot seem to get it into the desired format.  I have been working on what seems like should be fairly simple task for 3 days straight now.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged excel or data-structures?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) combined together:

```
from pandas.stats.moments import *

df.groupby(['ModelID', 'saledate']).transform(lambda x: expanding_mean(x.shift(1)))
```

Comment: Thank you but tried that and just two columns of machineID and SalesPrice comes up with nothing but 'NaN' values.